# matched row from one table

Tags: php, mysql

**I am shownig my question and effort both.**

I have a table student.

```
id   | name   | age | email | address | date
------------------------------
 1   | abc    | 20  | *abc@gmail.com*     |  street number10 | 14/07
------------------------------
 5   | abc    | 25  | *abc@gmail.com*     |  street number12 | 15/07
------------------------------
 8   | abc    | 25  | *abc@gmail.com*     |  street number10 | 15/07
------------------------------
12   | umnnn  | 20  | *umnn@gmail.com*    |  street number11 | 15/07
------------------------------
14   | umnnn  | 20  | *umnn@gmail.com*    |  street number10 | 14/07
------------------------------
15   | umnnn  | 25  | *umnn@gmail.com*    |  street number12 | 15/07
------------------------------
16   | hjk    | 25  | *hjk@gmail.com*     |  street number14 | 15/07
------------------------------
20   | hjk    | 20  | *hjk@gmail.com*     |  street number14 | 15/07
------------------------------
21   | hjk    | 23  | *hjk@gmail.com*     |  street number10 | 15/07
```

---

I want to match rows and want unmatched record **with date** based on **email**.

Example: for email id **hjk@gmail.com**

row 9th(id=21) should be matched with row 8th (id=20) and should give only unmatched value of 9th row means value of id=21, age=23, address=street number10 only, not should be other attributes.

Like (updated to 15/07 : id=21, age=23, street number10 only)

row 8th(id=20) should be matched with row 7th (id=16) and should give only unmatched value of 8th row means value of id=20, age=20 only.

***Like (updated to 15/07 : id = 20, age=20 * * *

**and with other email ids, operation will be like above * *

**My effort is:**

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sociale");

if(! $con )

{

  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());

}

$email=$_SESSION["email"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM  student where email='{$email}' and year='$year'";

$retval = mysqli_query( $con, $sql );


if(! $retval )

{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());

}

$cnt = mysqli_num_rows ( $retval );

if($cnt <=1)
{

   echo 'No Updates.';

}

else
{


   $retval = mysqli_query( $con, $sql );

   $except_last = array();

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retval))

  {

      $except_last[] = $row;

   }

  array_pop($except_last);



   $retval = mysqli_query( $con, $sql );

   $except_first = array();

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retval))

  {

      $except_first[] = $row;



   }

   array_shift($except_first);


   for($i=0;$i<count($except_first);$i++)

{


        $result = array_diff_assoc($except_first[$i], $except_last[$i]);

 $c=0;

        echo "<BR>";        

        foreach($result as $key=>$value){

        $c++;

        echo $key." = ".$value;

        if($c<count($result)) 

        {

                                  echo ", &nbsp; ";
       } 

   }

}

}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

**It gives unmatched value. But i want date too.**

For example for email hjk@gmail.com:

I want :updated to **15/07** : id=21, age=23, street number10

it gives :id=21, age=23, street number10 (Not giving date)

Please help.

Comment: You could add `$except_first[$i]['date']` to your 1st foreach loop -> `foreach($result as $key=>$value){ $c++; if($c==1) {echo "updated to ".$except_first[$i]['date']. " : ";} echo $key." = ".$value; ... }`

Comment: thank you very much...it works.  Now can i change the name of attribue. Because attribute name and original name are different (example: attribute name is age but original name is father age...So i want to show father age=23). father name has a space thats why i taken age.

Comment: So you want to change what `$key` echos? One way is to create an array of desired output with the `$key` as the key -> `$actualText = array('age'=>'father age',...);` and then in the loop -> `echo $actualText[$key]." = "...`

Comment: But i have an another problem that I want to latest update at top. But Latest updates or date going to below. So how can i solve it.