# How to replace attribute name by its original name?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table student.

```
 id   | name   | age | email               | address          | date
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1   | abc    | 20  | *abc@gmail.com*     |  street number10 | 14/07
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  5   | abc    | 25  | *abc@gmail.com*     |  street number12 | 15/07
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  8   | abc    | 25  | *abc@gmail.com*     |  street number10 | 15/07
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 12   | umnnn  | 20  | *umnn@gmail.com*    |  street number11 | 15/07
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 14   | umnnn  | 20  | *umnn@gmail.com*    |  street number10 | 14/07
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 15   | umnnn  | 25  | *umnn@gmail.com*    |  street number12 | 15/07
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 16   | hjk    | 25  | *hjk@gmail.com*     |  street number14 | 15/07
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 20   | hjk    | 20  | *hjk@gmail.com*     |  street number14 | 15/07
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 21   | hjk    | 23  | *hjk@gmail.com*     |  street number10 | 15/07
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here in the table, attribute name and original name are different (like: `name` is `father name`, `age` is `father age` and `email` is `father email`). So I want to print `father name` inplace of `age`, `father age` inplace of `age` and `father email` inplace of `email`.

Here is my code:

```
 <?php
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sociale");
 if(! $con )
 {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
 }
 $email=$_SESSION["email"];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM  student where email='{$email}' and year='$year'";
 $retval = mysqli_query( $con, $sql );
 if(! $retval )
 {
     die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
 }
 $cnt = mysqli_num_rows ( $retval );
 if($cnt &lt;=1)
 {
     echo 'No Updates.';
 }
 else
 {
     $retval = mysqli_query( $con, $sql );
     $except_last = array();
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retval))
     {
         $except_last[] = $row;
     }
     array_pop($except_last);
     $retval = mysqli_query( $con, $sql );
     $except_first = array();
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retval))
     {
         $except_first[] = $row;
     }
     array_shift($except_first);
     for($i=0;$i&lt;count($except_first);$i++)
     {
         $result = array_diff_assoc($except_first[$i], $except_last[$i]);
         $c=0;
         echo "<BR>";
         foreach($result as $key=&gt;$value){
             $c++;
             echo $key." = ".$value;
             if($c&lt;count($result))
             {
                 echo ", &nbsp; ";
             }
         }
     }
 }
 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Output of above code is to find unmatched record from two rows based on email.

For example for email hjk@gmail.com, the output is:

> updated to 15/07 : id=21, age=23, address=street number10

But I want:

> updated to 15/07 : id=21, **father age=23**, address=street number10

So how can I replace attributes name by its original name?

Comment: When asking question make sure that your question is readable. (indention code correctly, remove those large number of unnecessary empty lines and make your code formatted as code in SO)

Comment: I'm downvoting, for three reasons (hopefully my explanation is understandable and helpful). Firstly, the original version of this required way too much edit work. Secondly, it essentially duplicates the question you asked three hours ago, with a minor tweak in the question you are asking (and that required major edit work too). Thirdly, you seem to know we need prior effort here, but your evidence of effort for these two questions appears to be the same - and thus for each problem at hand, it does not seem you have tried at all.

Comment: This is the possible duplicate: [matched row from one table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842398/matched-row-from-one-table). Be aware that questions are for a wide audience here, so if you have to paste the same code twice, it is usually the case that the questions are essentially duplicates, even if you are asking about a slightly different problem. Please make a real effort when asking questions, not just the minimum sufficient for your question to be accepted. This is how to become a better programmer!

Answer (score 0):

You can build an array to give the correspondence between attribute names and original names.
The following should work :

- add the line :

  ```
  $correspondences=array("name"=>"father name","email"=>"father email", "age"=>"father age");
  ```
- replace the line

  ```
  echo $key." = ".$value;
  ```

  by

  ```
  if (array_key_exists($key,$correspondences)){  
   echo $correspondences[$key]." = ".$value;
  }else{
   echo $key." = ".$value;
  }
  ```

Comment: But i have an another problem that I want to latest update at top. But Latest updates or date going to below. So how can i solve it.

Comment: Ok , i got solution of my problem.

Comment: @user3526766: what was the solution? Please consider (a) posting a separate answer if you think it will be of help to someone else, and (b) upvoting and/or accepting answers you found helpful.

Comment: I have another question based on above question.... It gives all the unmatched value of particular email. But what about only last unmatched record, not all unmatched records. Like(updated to 15/07 : id=21, father age=23, address=street number10) only should be show.

Comment: Sort the result of your query according to decreasing `id` and only consider the first result : `$sql = "SELECT * FROM  student where email='{$email}' and year='$year' order by id desc limit 1";`